# Adding annotation text in lightningchart

Tags: lightningchart

Is there anyway to add Adding annotation text in lightningchart.

I looked into documentation , but I have not found any.

For example I want to add text - **Hello** in `x - 0 and y - 20`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create UI element, to add text to a chart, with [`chart.addUIElement`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v3.1.0/classes/chartxy.html#adduielement). To create specifically text, you can use [`UIElementBuilders.TextBox`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v3.1.0/globals.html#uielementbuilders.textbox).

To position the text on series scale:

```js
const textElement = chart.addUIElement(UIElementBuilders.TextBox, series.scale)
```

To position the text on two different axis:

```js
const textElement = chart.addUIElement(UIElementBuilders.TextBox, { x: chart.getDefaultAxisX(), y: chart.getDefaultAxisY() })
```

By default the text element is mouse draggable. To disable that you can call [`text.setDraggingMode(UIDraggingModes.notDraggable)`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v3.1.0/interfaces/uielement.html#setdraggingmode) ([UIDraggingModes documentation](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v3.1.0/enums/uidraggingmodes.html)).

The text font can be changed with [`text.setTextFont()`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v3.1.0/interfaces/uitextbox.html#settextfont).
Text fill style can be changed with [`text.setTextFillStyle()`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v3.1.0/interfaces/uitextbox.html#settextfillstyle).

The background style can be edited with [`text.setBackground()`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v3.1.0/interfaces/uitextbox.html#setbackground).

See full example below.

```js
const {
  lightningChart,
  UIElementBuilders,
  UIDraggingModes,
  LinearGradientFill,
  SolidLine,
  RadialGradientFill
} = lcjs

const lc = lightningChart()

const chart = lc.ChartXY()

const series = chart.addLineSeries()

series.add([{
  x: -1,
  y: 0
}, {
  x: 0,
  y: 30
}, {
  x: 1,
  y: 0
}])

const text = chart.addUIElement(UIElementBuilders.TextBox, series.scale)
  .setDraggingMode(UIDraggingModes.notDraggable)
  .setTextFont(f => f.setSize(30).setWeight(700).setStyle('normal'))
  .setTextFillStyle(new RadialGradientFill())
  .setBackground(b => b.setStrokeStyle(new SolidLine({
    thickness: 2,
    fillStyle: new LinearGradientFill()
  })))
  .setPosition({
    x: 0,
    y: 20
  })
  .setText('Hello')

const text2 = chart.addUIElement(UIElementBuilders.TextBox, {
    x: chart.getDefaultAxisX(),
    y: chart.getDefaultAxisY()
  })
  .setDraggingMode(UIDraggingModes.notDraggable)
  .setPosition({
    x: 0,
    y: 10
  })
  .setText('Hello, axis positioned')
```

```html
<script src="http://unpkg.com/@arction/lcjs@3.1.0/dist/lcjs.iife.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks , how can I disable the dragging and do the styling for font , size , color , border.

Comment: I have updated the answer to contain info on how to do those things.